# O que significa uma "!" exclamação antes de uma string dentro de um if em C#

Tags: c#, string

Olá, estou com uma duvida em relação a alguns "trechos" de um programa que estou usando para "estudar", a dúvida é, qual o significado de "!" dentro de um if antes de uma string, eu vi alguns tópicos no site explicando, más eu não entendo como funciona no programa que tenho...

`if (Connect._state == HostStatus.ONLINEALERT && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Connect._message))`

O código acima é um dos "trechos" que não entendo, agradeço desde já a quem me ajudar...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Em geral o operador "!" é o "not" lógico, ou seja, uma negação, acredito que seja o mesmo em C# como citado [aqui](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/boolean-logical-operators#logical-negation-operator-). Esse trecho provavelmente está negando `string.IsNullOrEmpty(Connect._message)`.

Answer (score 4):

então, string.IsNullOrEmpty indica se uma cadeia de caracteres é `null` ou `empty`, ou seja, caso essa variável `Connect._message` que está sendo passada como parâmetro seja `null` ou `empty`, ira retornar um boolean `true`, caso contrário irá retornar `false`, mas para satisfazer a condição do seu `If`, o valor retornado tem que ser `false`, por conta do sinal de exclamação.

exemplo:

```
var exemplo = null;    
if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(exemplo)){
//a condição deve ser true para prosseguir
//se a variavel exemplo for null ou empty, irá satisfazer a condição do If
//pois a condição pede que o valor seja null ou empty
}

var exemplo2 = 'teste';    
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(exemplo)){
//a condição deve ser false(por conta do !) para prosseguir
//ele verifica a variável, como nesse caso ela tem valor, o IsNullOrEmpty irá
//retornar false, pois não é null nem empty a variavel
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Em várias linguagens de programação você encontrará este caractere como um símbolo de negação. Ele nega um determinado valor.

Em seu exemplo: `!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Connect._message))`, o método `IsNullOrEmpty` está verificando se seu texto (`Connect._message`) é nulo ou vazio. Caso esta verificação retorne verdadeira (`true`), o símblo `!` negará esta informação fazendo com que o resultado final seja falso (`false`).

O mesmo ocorre no processo inverso, se o resultado de `IsNullOrEmpty` for falso (`false`), o símbolo `!` negará esta informação fazendo com que o resultado final seja verdadeiro (`true`).